# WWW::Mechanize and yellowpages.com

Tags: perl, module, mechanize, www-mechanize

I'm trying to search yellowpages.com via the Perl module WWW::Mechanize.

```
$mech->get( "http://www.yellowpages.com" );
$mech->form_name( "standard-searchform" );
$mech->field( "search-terms, "schneider" );
$mech->field( "search-location", "CA" );
$mech->submit();
```

I also tried $mech->submit_form( ... ) with the button value/type, but I get the following message all the time:

```
Error POSTing http://www.yellowpages.com/real_deals: Internal Server Error at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.pl line 39
```

Line 39 is

```
$mech->submit();
```

Is yp.com forwarding Mechanize to that site? How can I avoid that?

Comment: I've rolled back to Revision 1 because the question doesn't make sense otherwise. (Don't worry, we all make mistakes :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you've missed a `"` after search-terms. Looking at the source code of yellowpages, there is no form with name "standard-searchform". The form is with an id "searchform-form". So that example should work:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

$mech->get( "http://www.yellowpages.com" );
$mech->form_id( "searchform-form" );
$mech->field( "search-terms", "schneider" );
$mech->field( "search-location", "CA" );
$mech->submit();
```

EDIT:

also the search-terms and search-location are the input ids, where the documentation of the WWW::Mechanize says:

> Given the name of a field, set its value to the value specified

That means you should change them with: search_terms and geo_location_terms.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it in my post. I tried **searchform-form** as well and got the same error. Does the code work for you?

Comment: That's the id of the form, so it should be form_id instead of form_name

Comment: Thank you so much, I changed it to **form_id** and also changed IDs to names. Works now!